# Counting the number of inversions using Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, mergesort

I need to count the number of inversions using Merge Sort:

```
object Example {
 def msort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    def merge(left: List[Int], right: List[Int]): Stream[Int] = (left, right) match {
      case (x :: xs, y :: ys) if x < y => Stream.cons(x, merge(xs, right))
      case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => Stream.cons(y, merge(left, ys))
      case _ => if (left.isEmpty) right.toStream else left.toStream
    }

    val n = xs.length / 2
    if (n == 0) xs
    else {
      val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n
      merge(msort(ys), msort(zs)).toList
    }
  }                                              

  msort(List(8, 15, 3))                           
}
```

I guess I have to count it in the line (where `y < y`, the second line in `match`)

```
case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => Stream.cons(y, merge(left, ys))
```

However, when I tried I failed.

How do I do that?

**UPDATE**:

a version with an accumulator:

```
def msort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    def merge(left: List[Int], right: List[Int], inversionAcc: Int = 0): Stream[Int] = (left, right) match {
      case (x :: xs, y :: ys) if x < y => Stream.cons(x, merge(xs, right, inversionAcc))
      case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => Stream.cons(y, merge(left, ys, inversionAcc + 1))
      case _ => if (left.isEmpty) right.toStream else left.toStream
    }

    val n = xs.length / 2
    if (n == 0) xs
    else {
      val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n
      merge(msort(ys), msort(zs)).toList
    }
  }
```

How do I easily return `inversionAcc`? I guess, I can return it a part of tuple only like this:

```
def merge(left: List[Int], right: List[Int], invariantAcc: Int = 0): (Stream[Int], Int)
```

It doesn't look good, though.

**UPDATE2**:

and it actually doesn't count **properly**, I can't find where the error is.

Comment: Maybe you mean inversions?

Comment: :Perhaps these will help:
https://class.coursera.org/algo-2012-002/lecture/15                    
https://class.coursera.org/algo-2012-002/lecture/16

Comment: My solution in Frege might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968480/count-inversions-stackoverflowerror-in-frege-works-fine-in-haskell

Comment: @Aravind, it doesn't.

Comment: "When I tried I failed" -- show what you have tried, and where you have failed.

Comment: @n.m. I've already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Scala port of my [Frege solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14968480/367649).

```
object CountInversions {

  def inversionCount(xs: List[Int], size: Int): (Int, List[Int]) = 
    xs match {
        case _::_::_ => { //If the list has more than one element
          val mid = size / 2
          val lsize = mid
          val rsize = size - mid
          val (left, right) = xs.splitAt(mid)
          val (lcount, lsorted) = inversionCount(left, lsize)
          val (rcount, rsorted) = inversionCount(right, rsize)
          val (mergecount, sorted) = inversionMergeCount(lsorted, lsize, rsorted,
            rsize, 0, Nil)
          val count = lcount + rcount + mergecount
          (count, sorted)
        }
        case xs => (0, xs)
     }

  def inversionMergeCount(xs: List[Int], m: Int, ys: List[Int], n: Int, 
    acc: Int, sorted: List[Int]): (Int, List[Int]) = 
      (xs, ys) match {
        case (xs, Nil) => (acc, sorted.reverse ++ xs)
        case (Nil, ys) => (acc, sorted.reverse ++ ys)
        case (x :: restx, y :: resty) => 
          if (x < y) inversionMergeCount(restx, m - 1, ys, n, acc, x :: sorted)
          else if (x > y) inversionMergeCount(xs, m, resty, n - 1, acc + m, y :: sorted)
          else inversionMergeCount(restx, m - 1, resty, n - 1, acc, x :: y :: sorted)
      }

}
```

Comment: it's so complicated. does it have to be so?

Comment: This doesn't work for 2, 3, 9, 2, 9 where it outputs 1 inversion and should be 2

Answer (score 1):

If the solution doesn't have to be strictly functional then you can just add a simplistic counter:

```
object Example {
  var inversions = 0
  def msort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    def merge(left: List[Int], right: List[Int]): Stream[Int] = (left, right) match {
      case (x :: xs, y :: ys) if x < y => Stream.cons(x, merge(xs, right))
      case (x :: xs, y :: ys) =>
        inversions = inversions + 1
        Stream.cons(y, merge(left, ys))
      case _ => if (left.isEmpty) right.toStream else left.toStream
    }

    val n = xs.length / 2
    if (n == 0) xs
    else {
      val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n
      merge(msort(ys), msort(zs)).toList
    }
  }
}
Example.msort(List(8, 15, 3))
println(Example.inversions)
```

If it has to remain functional then you'll need to create an accumulator and thread it through all of the method calls and return a Pair from each function where the accumulator value is included in the return result, then sum the accumulator values for each merge convergence. (My functional-fu is not very good, I've already tried solving this functionally before trying the simple `var` approach.)

Comment: actually, it has to be, no "var" allowed.

Comment: Does it work? If your half-streams are (1,2) and (0, 3), how many inversions are there?

Comment: it does. I mean, I want there not to be "var". Look at my update please.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. Try msort(List(8, 15, 3, 1)). There should be 5 ones, but it says there are 3 of them which is wrong.

Comment: @MariusKavansky That's what I'm saying. Perhaps when you encounter the case of `y<x` there is more than one inversion.